# Laravel 9 email verification Invalid Signature

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, email-verification, signed-url

I've read all available solutions, but no chance. It always redirects to the 403 page with message (Invalid Signature).

Here is my route :

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

My env file :

```
APP_NAME='WebApp'
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:V4/NjIiHJMalSGiXqCfzDJJVF4BfDwJ8Hnxr1M8I2Lc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

MAIL_MAILER=log
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

But the provided link in log file is always invalid.

I'm using built in artisan sever `php artisan serve`

**Update :** This is the link in `laravel.log` file.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/verify/2/52e17b67fd82b0545bb4fbdc5748ed23104133c7?expires=3D1652547054&signature=3De8f38349c57d806fb67170ceee8e7300cbc40d61133e1f70c7929e843401db6a
```

I have tried `php artisan key:generate` and `php artisan config:cache`

The email is being send by laravel itself, I haven't customized anything.

Also I tried to override verify method provided by `VerifiesEmails.php` trait, but no chance. Here is what I did :

`VerificationController.php` :

```
public function verify(Request $request) {
    dd($request->fullUrl());
}
```

I got suspicious to the url according to some solutions but the url is all fine like above mentioned.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? Like log file, screenshot, error message, your email sending method

Comment: When you access the url and get a 403, is the protocol still http or it switched to https ?

Comment: Note that if you **send** the email and *then* run `artisan key:generate`, it clobbers the existing `APP_KEY` in `.env` and subsequent signature checks from links in all emails sent previously will fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After struggling 9 hours with this and hitting my head against the wall; finally I found out that the SIGNATURE is fine, but when laravel logs it in `laravel.log` file, it corrupts the file content and prefixes the SIGNATURE with this 2 characters `3D`.

This way everything breaks; I don't know why is this happening.

I won't delete this question in case others face this problem in future.

Comment: hi, currently having same problem, after finding out what is the cause, did you apply any fix that made it work?

Comment: @tapseoff -  I just stopped using the log file for storing the emails.

Answer (score 26):

For anyone still running into this issue try configuring the `TrustProxy` middleware if you have a similar configuration to the below

- Have set `URL::forceScheme('https');` in the `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider`
- Running laravel behind a reverse proxy

To get this working quickly, set the below in `TrustProxies.php` middleware.

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

For more information on configuring the `$proxies` setting, check out the official [Laravel documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies)

Comment: ah man i always forget this.... thnaks!

Comment: <3 you man, still has to be done on laravel 10

Comment: Isn't it unsafe, to use `protected $proxies = '*';`?

Comment: It is, (hence the `To get this working quickly` part). As per the documentation, you should set the specific IPs for your load balancer

Comment: What if you don't have a load balancer and you're working locally. Do we just add 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 3):

Man, you have just saved me this whole process.

In my case the PhpStorm also added `=` to the end of every line and `3D` was also in `expire=`

Thank you very much

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32035214)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my NGINX config was sending altered URLs, which was causing the signature verification to fail. I had copy/pasted from a different PHP site config, which was sending funny URL patterns.

More discussion: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/403-invalid-signature-every-time-i-try-to-verify-email-in-laravel-57

Corrected NGINX config:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Job Batches which have their own table in the database. There was an issue with one of the rows not having run and the exception message did mention `BusBatch` (something like that). To solve, I simply deleted the record from the database. Prior to noticing this issue, in Horizon, the batches tab would not get passed the loading circle. So if you're working with jobs and batches, this could be a lead.

I never encountered this problem before and seems like it could stem from many other things. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had mistakenly written my site address in `APP_URL` with `http` protocol while in Nginx configuration all `http` requests were redirected to `https`. so, when i changed

```
APP_URL=http://example.com
```

to

```
APP_URL=https://example.com
```

my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, for me editing `TrustProxy` middleware worked as well. I just want to add that I wasted some time ignoring this solution because I already had this implemented:

```
protected $proxies = [
    '*'
];
```

However it indeed only worked once I removed the * from the array:

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same case as you, i tried the following and it worked

Find folder `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/VerificationController.php`

```php
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        // $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify'); // -> change
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
```

I hope it helps you